# Both or vs. both and

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

Is it correct to say:

> I have both tea *or* coffee.

And does it differ from:

> I have both tea *and* coffee.

Answer (score 2):

"Or" certainly implies that you have **either one or the other, but not both**. You can't have both of them, yet have just one of them at the same time, so the first sentence doesn't make much sense. The second one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The conjunction *both* is used before two or more following things to stress that *they all are included*, whereas *or* always introduces *an alternative*.

Like you can't both have your cake and eat it, you can't have both something *or anything else -- it's always both one *and* the other or either one *or* the other